# Refactoring code for drawing draggable objects on canvas

Tags: javascript

I have a canvas on which I want to generate 12 soccers playerd. I created a class `Player`, which I create 11 times (for each of the players in the `players` array). The `Player` object calls the function to draw the correct elements on the canvas and make them draggable. The code is working, however I think the following parts probably not that great, especially the switch statements within the `Player` object. Could someone give me some tips on what to improve? (Not looking for someone to refactor it, just tips on what I could improve). Thanks!

Player object:

```
class Player {
  constructor(name, role, direction) {
    this.name = name;
    this.role = role;
    this.direction = direction;

    if (this.role === 'GK') {
      this.uniform = '../assets/img/uniform-keeper.png';
    } else {
      this.uniform = '../assets/img/uniform-player.png';
    }

    switch (this.direction) {
      case 'center': 
          this.yPosition = 110;
          break;
      case 'right-wing': 
          this.yPosition = 2;
          break;
      case 'right-center': 
          this.yPosition = 77;
          break;
      case 'left-center':  
          this.yPosition = 152;
          break;
      case 'left-wing':  
          this.yPosition = 222;
          break;
      default:
          this.yPosition = 110;
          break;
    }

    switch (this.role) {
      case 'GK':
          this.draw = new DraggablePlayer(this.name, this.role, this.uniform, this.color, 550, this.yPosition);
          break;
      case 'DF':
          this.draw = new DraggablePlayer(this.name, this.role, this.uniform, this.color, 420, this.yPosition);
          break;
      case 'MF':
          this.draw = new DraggablePlayer(this.name, this.role, this.uniform, this.color, 285, this.yPosition);
          break;
      case 'CF':
          this.draw = new DraggablePlayer(this.name, this.role, this.uniform, this.color, 160, this.yPosition);
          break;
      default:
          this.draw = new DraggablePlayer(this.name, this.role, this.uniform, this.color, 30, this.yPosition);
    } 
  }
}
```

Create Players from array

```
const players = [{
    name: 'De Gea',
    role: 'GK',
    direction: 'center'
  },{
    name: 'Danilio',
    role: 'DF',
    direction: 'right-wing'
  },{
    name: 'Ramos',
    role: 'DF',
    direction: 'right-center'
  },{
    name: 'Boateng',
    role: 'DF',
    direction: 'left-center'
  },{
    name: 'Marcelo',
    role: 'DF',
    direction: 'left-wing'
  },{
    name: 'Pogba',
    role: 'MF',
    direction: 'right-center'
  },{
    name: 'Kante',
    role: 'MF',
    direction: 'left-center'
  },{
    name: 'De Bruin',
    role: 'CF',
    direction: 'right-wing'
  },{
    name: 'Iniesta',
    role: 'CF',
    direction: 'left-wing'
  },{
    name: 'Messi',
    role: 'FW',
    direction: 'right-center'
  },{
    name: 'Ronaldo',
    role: 'FW',
    direction: 'left-center'
  }
];

for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  players[i] = new Player(players[i].name, players[i].role, players[i].direction);
  console.log(players[i]);
}
```

Function for making draggable objects

```
function DraggablePlayer(playerName, playerRole, playerUniform, playerColor, xPosition, yPosition){
  let that = this;
  let startX = 0;
  let startY = 0;
  let drag = false;

  let previousX;
  let previousY;

  this.x = xPosition;
  this.y = yPosition;

  this.update = function(){
    if (mousePressed) {
      let left = that.x;
      let right = that.x + playerWidth;
      let top = that.y; 
      let bottom = that.y + playerHeight;

      if (!drag) {
        startX = mouseX - that.x;
        startY = mouseY - that.y;
      }

      if (mouseX < right && mouseX > left && mouseY < bottom && mouseY > top) {
        if (!dragging){
          dragging = true;
          drag = true;
        }  
      }
    } else {
      drag = false;
    }

    if (drag) {
      that.x = mouseX - startX;
      that.y = mouseY - startY; 
      previousX = that.x; 
      previousY = that.y;
    }

    // Tag
    ctx.fillStyle = '#1fb74f';
    ctx.fillRect(that.x, that.y + 3, playerWidth / 3, playerHeight / 2);

    // Base
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillRect(that.x, that.y + 25, playerWidth, playerHeight - 10);

    // Name
    ctx.font = getFont(16);
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#292b2e';
    ctx.fillText(playerName, that.x + (playerWidth / 2), that.y + 50, playerWidth, playerHeight - 25);

    // Position
    ctx.font = getFont(13);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillText(playerRole, that.x + 17, that.y + 15, playerWidth, playerHeight);

    // Position image
    const uniformImage = new Image();
    uniformImage.src = playerUniform;

    ctx.drawImage(uniformImage, that.x + playerWidth / 2 - (playerWidth / 8), that.y, playerWidth / 3, playerHeight / 1.75);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got 3 suggestions.

1: A way to get rid of some of your copypaste in Player:

```
var num;
switch (this.role) {
    case 'GK':
        num = 550;
        break;
    case 'DF':
        num = 420;
        break;
    case 'MF':
        num = 285;
        break;
    case 'CF':
        num = 160;
        break;
    default:
        num = 30;
}
this.draw = new DraggablePlayer(this.name, this.role, this.uniform, 
this.color, num, this.yPosition);
```

2: Most important: If your code has inefficiencies, here's the best way to test for it. When debugging, create a startTime num, and then log the time your function took after it's done.

```
var startTime = Date.now();

//Do stuff

console.log("Finished xyz in " + Date.now() - startTime + " ms");
```

3: If you are doing anything animation related (which you are), always use requestAnimationFrame. This increases efficiency a LOT, because this lets the browser do any visual updates at the most efficient possible time, almost always resulting in smooth 60 fps. Here's an example. Check for mousedown and drag outside of your update function, then do your drawing and whatnot inside your objects.

```
var dragging = false;
var ticking = false;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
    dragging = true;
    if(!ticking){
        requestAnimationFrame(function(e){
            //Do your update stuff inside your objects and whatnot
            ticking = false;
            });
        ticking = true;
    }
});
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e){
    dragging = false;
});
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you! I will work on this and adding the requestAnimationFrame!

Comment: No problem! If you could upvote or mark my answer as correct, I'd super appreciate it, too. <3

Comment: You forgot an `if(ticking)` condition in your mousemove handler, here you don't use this flag, and you are simply stacking all the handlers to be executed at the same exact moment (which can even be worse than without using rAF at all)

Comment: Whooooooooopsies! Thanks, Kaiido. I was just writing that super quickly and completely forgot that check. Edited answer to show use of it